# Download image, then serve it NodeJS

Tags: node.js, image, mongodb, request, buffer

I am downloading an image from a URL and storing it in MongoDB.  After that I want to be able to serve the image to a client.  Here is my download code:

```
request({url: urlString, encoding: null }, 
function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        body = new Buffer(body, 'binary');
        Images.collection.insert({img: 
           { contentType: response.headers['content-type'], data: body}, 
             url: urlString}, function() {});
        }
})
```

Here is my endpoint code:

```
Images.findOne({url: query.url})
  .lean()
  .exec(function (err, doc) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    if(doc && doc.img) {
      res.contentType(doc.img.contentType);
      res.send(doc.img.data);
    }
  });
```

The result is a file much larger than the one originally downloaded. The record in mongo looks like it is still wrapped: "BinData(0,".  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Storing an image in MongoDB. Is your file system broken?

Comment: You should use `encoding: null` instead of `encoding: 'binary'`. That will make `body` a Buffer instance, which will avoid any encoding issues on the server side.

Comment: Updated code to reflect the new encoding, however the result is still a broken image.  Not sure how to paste the "result" of this though, making debugging quite difficult.

Comment: I was able to just use a FS scheme and have it working. Thanks all